# Ran into an issue involving lava

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I used a fire resistance potion to get under an ocean of lava, but forgot that I left my second one at home, so how do I escape? My picks are too low durability, and I don't have any wood.

And, it was in the nether with about 200 blocks to shore if I could swim in lava.

EDIT: Never mind, an admin is fixing it.

Comment: An admin is fixing what?

Comment: Please never comment or edit in "nevermind, my question solved itself". If it's a proper way of help that can work for others, self-answer, otherwise leave the question open, if you think that someone else might find a solution, or delete it.

Answer (score 1):

Lava oceans don't cover the entire floor of the Nether, some parts are netherrack. So you could dig to the sides and occasionally dig up, quickly blocking it off again if lava flows in.

Even if you have ender pearls, throwing one through the lava ocean and hoping to hit land won't work. Lava slows down ender pearls, so it would only land at the bottom again.

And if nothing helps, you can make a safe space under the lava ocean, blocked off from all sides, remember (or screenshot) your coordinates using the F3/debug screen, drop all your items into the safe space, close it off from the outside and take a refreshing bath in the lava. After your death, you take a fire resistance potion and a pickaxe, swim down there with fire resistance, make another safe space (so that lava doesn't flow to your items), then open the space with the items in it again and collect them.
This way you'll still lose a bit of in-game experience, but maybe you gained some real-life Minecraft experience from this situation. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, sometimes you have to deal with the consequences of venturing out unprepared.

In this situation it seems that the only solution, provided  you have access to commands in your game, is to set your gamemode to creative, teleport to a safe area or give yourself a fire resistance potion. If you can’t do this yourself you’ll need to have a server admin do it for you.

If this can’t be done it seems that there really isn’t any other way out of this situation. Sorry

Comment: The other, simple solution is to write down the coords, drop all your equipment into a safe hole, then take a swim in lava and after respawning return to pick the equipment, better prepared this time.